Trying to make a nav with half of the nav left aligned and half of the nav right aligned, with a logo in the center
Like the title says. I am trying to create a nav bar that will be fixed to the top of the screen. I want a logo in the front with 3 items aligned left and 3 items aligned right. No matter what I have tried, I cannot make the second set of 3 items align to the right.
I've spent an embarrassing amount of time on this.
This is my HTML:
    `<nav class="nav navbar-expand-sm">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="menu-btn" href="live.html">Live</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-btn" href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-btn" href="merch.html">Merch</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/small-logo.jpg" class="center-band-logo justify-content-center" width=16%></a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav" style="float:right">
                <li style="float:right"><a class="menu-btn" href="orderalbum.html">Album</a></li>
                <li style="float:right"><a class="menu-btn" href="tabs.html">Tabs</a></li>
                <li style="float:right"><a class="menu-btn" href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>`

This is my CSS:
.center-band-logo {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute; 
    border: 3px outset white;
    padding: 0%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.nav{
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar-nav{
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.menu-btn{
    color:white;
    padding-left: 85px;
    padding-right: 85px;
}

ul{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: right;
}

li{
    display: inline;
}

li a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div{
    overflow: auto;
}

Tried "display: block", tried "overflow: auto", changed the lists to divs and divs to lists and I can't even get anything to move even a tiny bit. Feels like I'm not even editing the same CSS file.
Thank you so much in advance.
I am in great despair
